# Difference between matching pattern and computing equality

Tags: java, regex, groovy

In the regular expression (Groovy) it has been told that "== ~" operator is similar to the operator 
" ==", but matches pattern instead of "computing equality" 
Could you please help me understand the actual difference between these two with a small example?

Comment: note, that the operator in question is `==~` and not `== ~`, which implies other generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x==y` is short for `x.equals(y)` or `x.compareTo(y)` -- see [Groovy Operator Overloading](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading) (where in java this basically compares object identity).

The operator `==~` is a specifically designed comparsion operator, to help you do a full match of a pattern on a string.

The generated code for the operator (e.g. disasm the code `'xxx' ==~ /xx?/`) is:

```
ScriptBytecodeAdapter.matchRegex("xxx", "xx?")
```

From [Groovy Regular Espressions](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions):

> Since a Matcher coerces to a boolean by calling its find method, the =~ operator is consistent with the simple use of Perl's =~ operator, when it appears as a predicate (in 'if', 'while', etc.). The "stricter-looking" ==~ operator requires an exact match of the whole subject string. It returns a Boolean, not a Matcher.

Answer (score 0):

"potatoe"=="potatoe" is actually:

```
boolean result = ("potatoe"=="potatoe") //Compare Strings (GStrings in groovy)
```

"potatoe"==~"potat.*" means:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("potat.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("potatoe");
boolean result = m.matches();
```

In first sample if you compare "potatoe" with "potat.*" the result will be false, because these two Strings are not equal. Second example uses matching, so "potat.*" is not a simple String anymore, but a regular expression and result will be true.